# Automapper: "Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping"

Tags: c#, automapper

AssertConfigurationIsValid Passes, and the object being tried is fully populated, but I get the error on the first Map request called.

I'm trying to map

```
Survey ToLoad = Mapper.Map<Survey>(U);
```

I'm initializing automapper with the code below.

```
//Lots of other Maps
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<User, SMUser>()
      .ForMember(t => t.AccountType, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.AccountType != null ? so.AccountType : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.Username, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.Username != null ? so.Username : String.Empty)));


Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<SurveyMonkey.Containers.Survey, Survey>().ForMember(t => t.AnalyzeUrl, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.AnalyzeUrl != null ? so.AnalyzeUrl : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.Category, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.Category != null ? so.Category : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.CollectUrl, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.CollectUrl != null ? so.CollectUrl : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.EditUrl, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.EditUrl != null ? so.EditUrl : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.Language, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.Language != null ? so.Language : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.Preview, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.Preview != null ? so.Preview : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.SummaryUrl, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.SummaryUrl != null ? so.SummaryUrl : String.Empty))
      .ForMember(t => t.Title, s => s.MapFrom(so => so.Title != null ? so.Title : String.Empty)) 
      //Some more members
);

//LISTS
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<List<SurveyMonkey.Containers.Collector>, List<Collector>>());

//Lots of other List Maps
```

I'm using the latest Stable version from Nuget (5.2.0).

Comment: Whats the error you get?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Only call `Mapper.Initialize` once with the whole configuration, or you will overwrite it.

You can wrap the configuration in a class that inherits `AutoMapper.Profile`:

```
using AutoMapper;

public class MyAutoMapperProfile : Profile {

    protected override void Configure() {
        CreateMap<User, SMUser>();
        CreateMap<SurveyMonkey.Containers.Survey, Survey>();
        CreateMap<List<SurveyMonkey.Containers.Collector>, List<Collector>>();
    }
}
```

Then initialize the Mapper using this Profile:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => {
    cfg.AddProfile<MyAutoMapperProfile>();
    cfg.AddProfile<OtherAutoMapperProfile>();
});
```

[AutoMapper Configuration](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Configuration)

Comment: This worked perfectly.(except the configure is protected not public?)

Comment: You are right, it is protected, I edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I got same error and in my startup class in ConfigureServices methode I use

`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(startup));` => startup class.

Because of that my automapper profile class (the class that inherit from `Automapper.Propfle`, in this case
`public class MyAutoMapperProfile : Profile`) not getting read.

To fix this I have replace `startup` class with the `MyAutoMapperProfile` like below
`services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(MyAutoMapperProfile));`.

you can debug and check whether your automapper mapping class getting hit or not.